# Numpy/PyTorch funny tensor product

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torch, algebra

I've got a 4 dimensional torch tensor parameter defined like this :

```
nn.parameter.Parameter(data=torch.Tensor((13,13,13,13)), requires_grad=True)
```

and four tensors with dims (batch_size,13) (or one tensor with dims (batch_size,4,13)).
I'd like to get a tensor with dims (batch_size) equal to the formula at the end of this picture :
[EDIT: I made a mistake in the first pict, I've corrected it]
[image]
I've seen in the torch documentation the function tensordot, but I can't manage to make it work by myself.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are indexing your output B with `i` but it is different than the mute variable on which you perform the outermost sum, right ?

Comment: Is `result = (A[None, :, :, :, :] * X[:, :, None, None, None] * Y[:, None, :, None, None] * Z[:, None, None, :, None] * T[:, None, None, None, :]).flatten(1).sum(dim=1)` what you want? If so I can post the answer with an explanation.

Comment: The only reason I'm confused and not posting as answer is the use of subscript i on the left and right side of the equation you posted.

Comment: @trialNerror I've corrected my picture, and you're right, I had to add a b variable for batch elements.

Comment: @jodag I'm not sure this is what I'm trying to do, as X, Y, Z and T in your equation are tensors of dims 5 but mines are tensors of dims 2.

Comment: If A is a tensor of dims 3, then I manage to do it with torch.bmm(torch.unsqueeze(z,2),torch.bmm(torch.unsqueeze(y,1),torch.transpose(torch.matmul(x,A),0,1))).sum(axis=2).sum(axis=1)

Comment: @Jogima_cyber No A is 4 dimensional and X, Y, Z, and T are 2 dimensional as you indicated in your picture. The `None` indexing is just used to insert unitary dimensions just like in numpy. This is the broadcasted equivalent to the einsum expression of Shai's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever you have a funny tensor product [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html#torch.einsum) (or [`numpy.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)) is your friend:

```py
batch_size = 5
A = torch.rand(13, 13, 13, 13)
a = torch.rand(batch_size, 13)
b = torch.rand(batch_size, 13)
c = torch.rand(batch_size, 13)
d = torch.rand(batch_size, 13)
B = torch.einsum('ijkl,bi,bj,bk,bl->b', A, a, b, c, d)
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, didn't know of this function. Can it work on gpu too ?

Comment: @Jogima_cyber `torch.einsum` is part of pytorch basic operations. Not only does it works on cpu/gpu but also it propagates gradients to the input tensors.

Comment: So great, so complex hidden computations.